# Value at $(0,0)$ of the solution to a 2D linear elliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The setup is the following.

Let $D=(-\frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{2})^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $\partial D$ be its boundary. Let $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ be continuous on $\partial D$. Also we assume that $f$ is **periodic** in the sense that $f(\frac{1}{2},x_2) = f(-\frac{1}{2},x_2)$ and $ f(x_1, \frac{1}{2})= f(x_1, -\frac{1}{2})$. Consider the equations $$\Delta u+ax_1 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+bx_2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2} = 0 \text{ ,  on } D \text{;}$$ $$u|_{\partial D} = f \text{ .}$$

I would like to know if there is an explicit or approximate solution to this PDE.

Actually, I am only interested in the value $u(0,0)$ or its approximation.

Thank you!

Comment: You can switch to polar coordinates, assume a Fourier series solution and obtain a system of ODEs for the radial part. But I'm not sure to how to solve it due to the recurring relations.

Comment: @Dylan, I changed the domain to a more "natural" one, making it more convenient for Fourier series. Could you please try again with this one?

Comment: I don't think a periodic is possible in the new setting, so the Fourier method may not work here. It is more easily separated, though. But again, I'm not sure how to solve the separated equations.

Answer (score 0):

This equation appears like it can be solved by using separation of variables. Assume there exists a separable solution
$$u(x_1,x_2) = X_1(x_1)X_2(x_2)$$
Plugging this into the original PDE allows the two variables to be separated with eigenvalue of $\lambda_n$
$$X_1''+ax_1X'_1-\lambda_n X_1=0\quad\&\quad X_2''+bx_2X_2'+\lambda_n X_2=0$$
These equations are not easily solvable. They can be solved assuming power series solution, but Mathematica is much more clever in recognizing the power series to be previously studied functions
$$X_1(x_1;\lambda_n)=e^{-\frac{ax_1^2}{2}}\left[g_1(x_2)\;H_{\frac{\lambda_n}{a}-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}\;x_1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+g_2(x_2)\;_1F_1\left(\frac{a-\lambda_n}{2a};\frac{1}{2};\frac{ax_1^2}{2}\right)\right]$$
$$X_2(x_2;\lambda_n) = e^{-\frac{bx_2^2}{2}}\left[h_1(x_1)\;H_{-\frac{\lambda_n}{b}-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{b}\;x_2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+h_2(x_1)\;_1F_1\left(\frac{b+\lambda_n}{2b};\frac{1}{2};\frac{bx_2^2}{2}\right)\right]$$
where $H_i$ are the Hermite polynomials and $_1F_1$ is the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind (I've never studied this one) and $g$ and $h$ are arbitrary functions of $x_2$ and $x_1$ respectively. $g$ and $h$ are dependent on $f$, so they can be found when $f$ is known.

The most general solution would be to sum over all the eigenfunctions
$$u = \sum_nX_1(x_1;\lambda_n)X_2(x_2;\lambda_n)$$
however, since you are interested in $u(0,0)$ we can understand a little more without knowing $f$. Using 
$$_1F_1(\cdot;\cdot;0) = 1\quad\&\quad H_i(0) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\;2^i}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-i}{2}\right)}$$
we can see that the solution at the origin would look like
$$u(0,0) = \sum_n\left[g_1(0)\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\;2^{-\frac{\lambda_n}{a}-1}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{\lambda_n}{2a}\right)}+g_2(0)\right]\left[h_1(0)\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\;2^{\frac{\lambda_n}{b}-1}}{\Gamma\left(1-\frac{\lambda_n}{2b}\right)}+h_2(0)\right]$$
Again, $g$ and $h$ are dependent on $f$. 
Not sure if this approach is what you were looking for. I think there may be a more elegant approach.

Comment: How can $X1(x_1)$ be dependent on $x_2$ and vice versa? Shouldn't $g$ and $h$ just be constants?